Finding function $u(x,y)$ when $u\left(x=0,y\right)=y^2.$
today I am trying to solve $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\left(2x-y\right)u=0$$ and finding function $u(x,y)$ when $u\left(x=0,y\right)=y^2.$
I tried using characteristic equations to write
$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{2}=\frac{du}{-(2x-y)u}$ and then get $2x-y=c_1$.
From second equation I got $\frac{du}{dx}=-c_1u$.
Now I am not sure, but I write $e^{c_1 x}(-u)=c_2$ $\implies -ue^{(2x-y)x}=c_2,$ $c_2=F(c_1)$ with $F$ being arbitrary function.
Then $-ue^{(2x-y)x}=F(2x-y)$ and $u=u(x,y)=-\frac{F(2x-y)}{e^{(2x-y)x}}.$
If this is correct so far, I don't get how to do second part of the problem in finding the function.
After some calculations, I got $F(-y)=-y^2$, not sure what I do about $F(2x-y)$ part.

If $F(-y) = -y^2$ for all $y$, $F(2x-y) = -(y-2x)^2$.
